# Simple closed curves in a simply connected domain

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, plane-geometry, path-connected, jordan-curves

Let $U$ be a bounded simply connected domain in the plane. Let $K$ be the boundary (or frontier) of $U$. For every $\varepsilon>0$ is there a simple closed curve $S\subset U$ such  that the Hausdorff distance between $S$ and $K$ is $<\varepsilon$?

I'm aware that there is an $S$ such that every point of $S$ is within $\varepsilon$ of some point of $K$. That is the Zoretti Theorem. But what I'm asking here is slightly different.

Comment: With the notations of the given answer, the sequence of sets $h(\overline B_r)$ gives an exhaustion of $U$ by compact sets, and it is known that the Hausdorff distance behaves well under increasing sequence of nonempty compact sets, namely $d_H(h(\overline B_r),\overline U)\to0$ as $r\to1$. In particular $d_H(\Gamma_r,\partial U)\to0$.

Comment: But the last implication is not immediate, although it's based on standard facts. Since it is the point of the question it seems safer to give a complete proof.

Comment: Sure, I agree !

Comment: (for instance $X_k:=\{x: 1/k\le \|x\|\le 1-1/k\}$ is increasing and converges to $\overline B_1$ but $\partial X_k$ does not converge to $\partial B_1$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B_r(y)\subset\mathbb C$ denote the open disk of radius $r$ and center $y\in\mathbb C$, and  $B_r:=B_r(0)$. Let $h:B_1\to U$ a homeomorphism (e.g. a Riemann mapping) . Then  $\Gamma_r:=h(\partial B_r)$ is a simple closed curve in $U$ for $0<r<1.$  Moreover

- For any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $0<\rho<1$ such that for all $\rho<r<1$ there holds $\Gamma_r \subset \partial U  + B_\epsilon$. Indeed
  $h^{-1}\big(U\setminus(\partial U + B_\epsilon)\big)$ is a compact
  subset of $B_1$, so it is included in some $B_\rho$ for $\rho<1$,
  whence  $U\setminus(\partial U + B_\epsilon)\subset h(B_\rho)$, that
  is $\Gamma_r\subset h(B_1\setminus B_\rho)\subset \partial U +
     B_\epsilon$ for all $\rho<r<1$.
- For any $\epsilon>0$ there exist $\sigma>0$ such that for all $\sigma<r<1$ there holds $\partial U\subset \Gamma_r + B_\epsilon$. This follows easily by compactness, arguing by contradiction: otherwise, there would exist  $\epsilon_0>0$ such that for a sequence $r_k <1$, $r_k\to 1$ and $y_k\in\partial U$ one has $\emptyset\neq \partial U\setminus (\Gamma_{r_k} + B_{\epsilon_0})\ni y_k$, that is $ B_{\epsilon_0}(y_k)\cap \Gamma_{r_k}=\emptyset.$ Up to extracting a sequence , $y_k\to y_\infty\in\partial U$ and $ B_{\epsilon_0/2}(y_\infty)\cap \Gamma_{r_k}=\emptyset$ eventually, a contradiction because since $y_\infty\in\partial U$, any nbd of $y_\infty$ contains points of $\Gamma_r$ for all $r<1$ close enough to $1$.

Therefore the Hausdorff distance is $d_{\mathcal H}(\partial U, \Gamma_r)=o(1)$ as $r\to 1$.

Comment: Why is the last sentence of the second bullet true? That is, why are all points of $\partial U$ approached by $\Gamma_r$ as $r$ tends to one?  I see this holds when $h$ extends continuously to $\partial B_1$.  But there are examples where that does not happen...

Comment: In the notations above, let $A$ be the connected component of $y_\infty$ in $U\cap  B_{\epsilon_0/2}(y_\infty)$.  Then $h^{-1}(A)$  is a connected open subset of $B_1$ whose closure meets  $\partial  B_1$.  It follows that  the  set of $r<1$ such that  $\partial  B_r\cap V\neq \emptyset$ is a  non-empty interval  $(a,1)$, which gives the last sentence  applying $h$.

Comment: Since $y_\infty$ is not a point of $U$ it does not lie in the intersection $U \cap B_{\epsilon_0/2}(y_\infty)$.  So $A$ is not well-defined.  Perhaps the following works: "let $A$ be any connected component of $U \cap B_{\epsilon_0/2}(y_\infty)$."  Also, is $V = h^{-1}(A)$, on the last line?

Comment: Yes, exactly,  that’s what I was also thinking.  I think it is OK because any connected component  $A$  has a closure that meets  $\partial U$.  Yes, $V=h^{-1}(A)$. Thank you!